# What are the reasons the United States did not support the creation of the International Criminal Court?

Tags: united-states, international-courts

In reading the [Wikipedia article on the International Criminal Court](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Criminal_Court), I learned that the United States did not support the court's creation, but no reason was given. For what reasons did the United States not support the court's creation? Does that in any way relate to the current [claim by John Bolton (White House national security adviser) that the court is illegitimate](http://thehill.com/homenews/administration/405818-bolton-to-label-international-criminal-court-illegitimate-report)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_and_the_International_Criminal_Court might be of interest

Comment: Wasn't there a question on this earlier on the site?

Comment: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/929/why-has-the-united-states-not-signed-and-ratified-the-international-criminal-cou?rq=1 this one I think

Comment: @user4012 Yes, I'd say that's a duplicate.